# Fetched Emails not ordered when I use pop3

Tags: c#, gmail, pop3, mailkit

First I were Fetching emails by POP3 using this library OpenPop.Pop3 and it was working ok and it was returns emails ordered from last email to first email 
but when I change the library to mailkit library the returned messages not ordered and couldn't know based on what mailkit order fetched emails 
that's my code after I change to mailkit library

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            // Connect to the server
            client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            client.Authenticate((username), password);
            int messageCount = client.Count;

            // We want to download all messages
            List<MimeMessage> allMessages = new List<MimeMessage>(messageCount);

            for (int i = messageCount-1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                    var msg = client.GetMessage(i);
                    allMessages.Add(msg);
            }
         }
```

by this way allmessages variable should contains emails ordered from last email to first email but that's not happened emails not ordered at all
although I were using the same authenticated email before with OpenPop.Pop3 and fetched emails were ordered

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why they wouldn't be ordered for you since MailKit is not doing any kind of sorting.

That said, MailKit uses 0-based indexes while I suppose OpenPOP.NET must have used 1-based indexes, so your loop should make the following change:

```
for (int i = messageCount-1; i >= 0; i--)
{
    var msg = client.GetMessage(i);
    allMessages.Add(msg);
}
```

Perhaps this will produce the expected results?

**Update:** It turns out that MailKit was correctly downloading the messages in reverse order just as his code was trying to do (as mentioned in his [follow-up question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53316125/pop3-not-fetch-newest-emails)). The problem this user was facing is that his GMail account settings were only providing MailKit's Pop3Client with a subset of his total Inbox as is explained in Google's [FAQ](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13291) in the section titled "Emails aren't downloading correctly", where it states:

> After you set up POP in your Gmail settings, your emails become available
>   in batches. It might take a while to see all your emails.
>
> Note: Gmail downloads a copy of every email you send or receive, except 
>   for emails in Chats, Spam, and Trash. To avoid duplicates, Gmail doesn't 
>   download emails sent within your mail client, but you can still see them 
>   if you log in to Gmail.
>
> If you continue to have problems downloading emails, try using recent 
>   mode:
>
> 1. In your email client's POP settings page, find the "Email address" or 
>      "User name" field.
> 2. Add recent: in front of your email address. For example, 
>      recent:example@gmail.com.
>
> If that doesn't fix the problem, try deleting your Gmail address from your email client, then re-adding it.

Comment: 0 should return last entered email , but the problem this code not order emails !!

Comment: I just need to fetch always the new emails

Comment: `client.GetMessage(0)` returns the oldest message stored on the POP3 server.

Comment: Why do you think they aren't "sorted" properly? What are you using as a basis for this claim? POP3 uses indexes to refer to messages. MailKit uses indexes to refer to messages. There is no sorting that is happening at all inside MailKit.