# POP3 not fetch newest emails on GMail

Tags: c#, gmail, pop3, mailkit

I use mailkit pop3 to fetch emails, but I find it didn't fetch newest emails and each time I run it return different messages count number

```
using (Pop3Client client = new Pop3Client())
        {
            // Connect to the server
            client.Connect(hostname, port, useSsl);
            client.AuthenticationMechanisms.Remove("XOAUTH2");
            client.Authenticate((username), password);
            int messageCount = client.Count;
           // var folder = client.;

            // We want to download all messages
            List<MimeMessage> allMessages = new List<MimeMessage>(messageCount);

            for (int i = messageCount - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                var msg = client.GetMessage(i);
                allMessages.Add(msg);
            }
        }
```

I supposed that all messages variable should be filled with all emails ordered from newest emails to old emails but I found all messages return old emails and not contains at all new emails at all, I searched a lot and didn't find the reason, Do you know why that happened and how can I fix that ?
I wish to find any help here and Thanks in advance

Comment: Didn't you ask the same question already: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53303349/fetched-emails-not-ordered-when-i-use-pop3

Comment: I didn't clear in old question that fetched emails not contains the newest emails, and I said it's not ordered but i found the problem it fetch group of old ordered emails but not get the newest emails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you connecting to GMail, by any chance?

This is a GMail behavior where, depending on your POP settings (as set in the GMail web app Settings page), will determine what messages the client sees.

This is not a MailKit issue.

From Google's own [FAQ](https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13291) in the section titled "Emails aren't downloading correctly", it states:

> After you set up POP in your Gmail settings, your emails become available
>   in batches. It might take a while to see all your emails.
>
> Note: Gmail downloads a copy of every email you send or receive, except 
>   for emails in Chats, Spam, and Trash. To avoid duplicates, Gmail doesn't 
>   download emails sent within your mail client, but you can still see them 
>   if you log in to Gmail.
>
> If you continue to have problems downloading emails, try using recent 
>   mode:
>
> 1. In your email client's POP settings page, find the "Email address" or 
>      "User name" field.
> 2. Add recent: in front of your email address. For example, 
>      recent:example@gmail.com.
>
> If that doesn't fix the problem, try deleting your Gmail address from your email client, then re-adding it.

Comment: but when I use OpenPop.Mime.Message I were getting all newest emails always
with the same gmail setting

Comment: and after i change to mailkit i logined to gmail account and look at settings again and Enable POP for all mail (even mail that's already been downloaded)
but I still not get newest emails , and i don't know based on what it retrieve emails

Comment: What are the odds that I was able to correctly guess your pop server based on your question if I’m wrong? 0.

Comment: Read this: https://mail.google.com/support/bin/answer.py?answer=13291 - specifically, read the link “ Emails aren’t downloading correctly”

Comment: I applied that before and i checked Enable POP for all mail  multiple times and i still get same problem !! .... once i returned my old code with the same gmail settings emails feched with no problem !!

Comment: You can thank me by upvoting and accepting my answers. Thanks.

Comment: Ok but i still not reached to issue

Comment: See my updated answer. How does that not resolve this issue? Google's own FAQ explains why MailKit's Pop3Client is downloading random batches of messages. The FAQ that I linked you to also explains how to get around this.

Comment: oh my god !! I think it's working now :D Thanks a lot

Comment: I marked your reply as answer but i couldn't up vote your answer it's not allowed to me now to up vote ,sorry

Comment: Okay, thanks for trying - maybe you need more reputation?